# Npm can't find module "semver" error in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dependencies, 19.04, npm

I am getting the following error whenever I try to run npm command.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I was basically trying to make offline use of FreeCodeCamp. It asked me to run command 'npm ci' from which I started getting this error.

I tried reinstalling npm but it won't work. I also tried installing the semver module which also didn't help.

What might have gone wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/1438491) and the answer worked.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Download the latest `tar.xz` NodeJS file from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

```
tar -xf node-v#.#.#-linux-x64.tar.xz
sudo mv node-v#.#.#-linux-x64/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
sudo mv node-v#.#.#-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/
```

Where `#.#.#` is the version you downloaded.

Verify installation using

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 20, module still missing

Comment: this has node, but not npm

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you want to manage Node JS/npm.

As Bilbo Baggins suggested, you can install the latest LTS version of Node JS from the official website: https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

On Ubuntu, if you would rather manage Node through the default repositories using `apt`, it's best to install both `nodejs` and `npm` this way.

It's very likely that the version of npm you are using is expecting `semver` in a specific place that is not aligned with the version of Node JS you have installed. If there is only one version of `nodejs` and only one version of `npm`, and they are both installed using the default repositories, this should work perfectly.

Here is my best guidance for getting Node and npm working using the main Ubuntu repositories:

0. `sudo apt-get purge nodejs --auto-remove` and `sudo apt-get purge npm --auto-remove`
1. `whereis node`: remove all the versions of node, one at a time. Repeat until this command returns a blank after `node:`.
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
3. `node --version`: should return `... no such file or directory`
4. `nodejs --version`: should return `v1x.x.x`. This is the version installed by `apt`. It will probably be less recent that the latest version available on the Node JS website.
5. `sudo apt-get install npm`
6. `npm --version`: it will use the `nodejs` installed by `apt` and work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I was using nvm to manage node versions, In my case npm syslink was broken i solved it by uninstalling and then reinstalling node again

check your node version using `node --version`

then run `nvm uninstall <your version>`

then reinstall using `nvm install <your version`

Answer (score 3):

Run this command it will automatically remove previous version of npm and install new version of npm, worked for me, you can check here for details https://github.com/npm/cli

```
 curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to run it as root.

Comment: Yes you have to run via sudo

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but on 22.04.  None of the above worked for me, but I found this process that did.  https://codemarvels.in/2021/03/20/npm-install-gives-error-cannot-find-module-semver/
Essentially:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Comment: works for my ubuntu 22

Answer (score 1):

I was facing an Angular project. Somehow, Angular-CLI (ng) was removed.
So I just verified that `node` and `npm` are installed and did the following which fixed it:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using nvm so I had to remove all node versions (rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/*)
then install both nodejs and npm :

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command resolved problem on my Ubuntu 22.04 PC.

```sh
hash -r
```

`n` command said

```
If "node --version" shows the old version then start a new shell, or reset the location hash with:
hash -r  (for bash, zsh, ash, dash, and ksh)
rehash   (for csh and tcsh)
```

The command I install latest version of npm to Ubuntu22.04.

```sh
sudo apt install -y npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
hash -r
npm --version
```