# Why is the semver error happening?

Tags: nodejs, npm

```
$ npm install

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19) {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm can't find module "semver" error in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152570/npm-cant-find-module-semver-error-in-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: voting to close. Not really enough information to be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, if you would rather manage Node through the default repositories using `apt`, it's best to install both `nodejs` and `npm` this way.

It's very likely that the version of npm you are using is expecting `semver` in a specific place that is not aligned with the version of Node JS you have installed. If there is only one version of `nodejs` and only one version of `npm`, and they are both installed using the default repositories, this should work perfectly.

Here is my best guidance for getting Node and npm working using the main Ubuntu repositories:

0. `sudo apt-get purge nodejs --auto-remove` and `sudo apt-get purge npm --auto-remove`
1. `whereis node`: remove all the versions of node, one at a time. Repeat until this command returns a blank after `node:`.
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
3. `node --version`: should return `... no such file or directory`
4. `nodejs --version`: should return `v1x.x.x`. This is the version installed by `apt`. It will probably be less recent that the latest version available on the Node JS website.
5. `sudo apt-get install npm`
6. `npm --version`: it will use the `nodejs` installed by `apt` and work correctly.

Comment: How should I "remove all version of node", as you said in point 1?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just don't have the semver module.
Ubuntu might be using some old nodejs version & it doesn't have it.

You can check running following cmds:
Ubuntu nodejs version: `nodejs -v`
Version you installed: `node -v`

You gotta make sure you're using the one you installed.
Since it's probably a newer version which will have the semver package already.

Personally, I installed `nvm` and then ran:
`nvm install node` (should install the latest version)
following with: `nvm list` or `nvm ls` to see your available versions.

If you're not using the latest version you've just installed then run:
`nvm use <version>`
In my case, as of the time writing this, my version is 19.8.0
So I'd use `nvm use 19.8.0`

then try to run npm & whatever command didn't work before.

You can also set the node default version with this command:
`nvm alias default 19.8.0`
if any problems in the future check again what version you're using with `nvm ls`.